# Error during building process of Next Js application

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, fetch-api, next.js13

I am trying to build a website using nextjs by hosting it on Vercel. However, during the building process, I keep running into these error:

```
- info Loaded env from E:\Programming\Web Dev\Personal Websites\blogposts\.env
- info Creating an optimized production build  
- info Compiled successfully
- info Linting and checking validity of types  
- info Collecting page data
[=   ] - info Generating static pages (5/7)TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11600:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  cause: AggregateError
      at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1114:18)
      at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1667:5)
      at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {    
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    [errors]: [ [Error], [Error] ]
  }
}
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'allBlogs' of '(intermediate value)' as it is undefined.     
    at BlogList (E:\Programming\Web Dev\Personal Websites\blogposts\.next\server\app\page.js:450:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error   
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'allBlogs' of '(intermediate value)' as it is undefined.     
    at BlogList (E:\Programming\Web Dev\Personal Websites\blogposts\.next\server\app\page.js:450:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
- info Generating static pages (7/7)

> Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /page: /
```

The whole [project file](https://github.com/Gamoventure1175/nextjs-blogon) is hosted on GitHub.

I have setup the CRUD project using MongoDB and Mongoose. I built 2 api files as you can see in the project and I fetch data from these API's using "fetch" command.

Everything works fine when I do `npm run dev` and the website loads fine on the local server, there are no such errors but when I do `npm run build`, I get the above errors.

I suppose the problem comes in my BlogList.jsx component:

```js
import React from 'react';
import RemoveBtn from './RemoveBtn';
import Link from 'next/link';
import {AiFillEdit} from 'react-icons/ai';

const getBlogs = async() => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/blogs", {
      cache: 'no-store'
    })

    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error("Failed to fetch blog posts");
    }
    return res.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }

}

async function  BlogList() {

  const {allBlogs} = await getBlogs();

  return (
    <>
    {allBlogs.map((blog) => (
      <div className="flex justify-between rounded-xl p-3 sm:max-3xl:p-4 w-fit  bg-red-200 text-black shadow-lg shadow-red-300 my-3 border border-red-200 hover:border hover:border-white ">
        <div className="text-sm sm:max-3xl:text-lg">
          <h2 className="text-xl sm:max-3xl:text-2xl sm:max-3xl:mb-3 font-semibold mb-2">{blog.title}</h2>
          <div className="my-2 sm:max-3xl:my-3">
              {blog.body}
          </div>
          <div className="text-base sm:max-3xl:text-lg">
              {blog.author}
          </div>
          <i className=" text-xs font-semibold sm:max-3xl:text-sm text-gray-600">
              {blog.updatedAt} 
          </i>
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-col-reverse justify-between items-end text-base sm:max-3xl:text-xl sm:max-3xl:ml-3 ml-1 py-1">
          <RemoveBtn id={blog._id} />
          <Link href={`/editBlog/${blog._id}`}>
              <AiFillEdit />
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}

export default BlogList;
```

If anyone knows the solution, please can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from the fetch function, because it is trying to hit localhost while it is not running.

Did you try running npm run dev, and while the server is up, build your project with npm run build?

That could solve the issue.

Apart from that, I would use the localhost:3000 hardcoded in the fetch function, but instead you could have a env variable to know where to make the api call. That has nothing to do with your problem but it is just a recommendation!

Hope it helps